# Shortest distance from a point to this curve

Tags: c#, geometry, linear-programming

I need to find the distance of multiple points to a curve of the form: `f(x) = a^(k^(bx))`

My first option was using its derivative, using a line of the form with the inverse of the derivative, giving it coordinates of the `Point` and intersecting it with the original curve. Finally, we calculate the distance between points with simple geometry.

That's the mathematical process that I usually follow. I need to save time (since I'm doing a genetic algorithms program) so I need an efficient way to do this. Ideas?

Comment: I think you're on the right path by using the derivative, but since a true derivative could get difficult in code, you could fake it and compute the slope of the tangent line by computing a short sample line between the points (x, f(x)) and (x+h, f(x+h)) where h is some tiny value.  The genetic part could be making h smaller and smaller as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distance between a point (c,d) and your curve is the minimum of the function

```
sqrt((c-x)^2 + (d-a^(k^(bx)))^2)
```

To find its minimum, we can forget about the `sqrt` and look at the first derivative. Find out where it's 0 (it has to be the minimal distance, as there's no maximum distance). That gives you the x coordinate of the nearest point on the curve. To get the distance you need to calculate the y coordinate, and then calculate the distance to the point (you can just calculate the distance function at that `x`, it's the same thing).

Repeat for each of your points.

The first derivative of the distance function, is, unfortunately, a kind of bitch. Using [Wolfram's derivator](http://library.wolfram.com/webMathematica/Education/WalkD.jsp), the result is *hopefully* (if I haven't made any copying errors):

```
dist(x)/dx = 2(b * lna * lnk * k^(bx) * a^(k^(bx)) * (a^(k^(bx)) - d) - c + x)
```

Comment: if the amount of points will be high (using floats for example) using your method isn't possible because of calculation complexity. Just brutforcing all the dot's id impossible if you have a lot of dots.

Comment: @zmbq You mean taking the first derivative of (c-x)^2 + (d-a^(k^(bx)))^2 ?   I then find where the derivative is equal to 0, which will give me an x, right? Not the distance itself. I need to re-input the x in the original equation and compute, true?

Comment: If he needs the distance between all the points and the curve, I don't believe he has a choice.

Comment: @Fiire, yes, exactly. I'll elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

To find distance from point to curve it's not a simple task, for that you need to find the global of function [image] where f(x) is the function which determine your curve.

For that goal you could use:
 [Simplex method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm)
 [Nelder_Mead_method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method)
 [gradient_descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)

This methods implemented in many libraries like [Solver Foundation](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation), [NMath](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath/) etc.